# How to disable other options after if an option is selected in MUI Select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield

Is it possible to change the select options of the `Select` based on other selects values?

```
so for example:
if I have lets say A and B
if you select A
then you can select in the other textfield C and D
but if you selected B 
then you can select E and F
```

Visual example:

So I have this 2 options

[image]

and when I select David I only want to show up till 6 and not 7,8,9,10 etc

[image]

[image]

and then if you select the other one then show everything

The options:

```
const grados = 
      [{value: "Prekínder-3", label: "Prekínder-3"},
       {value: "Prekínder", label: "Prekínder"},
       {value: "Kínder", label: "Kínder"},
       {value: "1° Grado", label: "1° Grado"},
       {value: "2° Grado", label: "2° Grado"},
       {value: "3° Grado", label: "3° Grado"},
       {value: "4° Grado", label: "4° Grado"},
       {value: "5° Grado", label: "5° Grado"},
       {value: "6° Grado", label: "6° Grado"},
       {value: "7° Grado", label: "7° Grado"},
       {value: "8° Grado", label: "8° Grado"},
       {value: "9° Grado", label: "9° Grado"},
       {value: "10° Grado", label: "10° Grado"},
       {value: "11° Grado", label: "11° Grado"},
       {value: "12° Grado", label: "12° Grado"}]

       const sedes = 
       [{value: "Academia Internacional Boquete", label: "Academia Internacional Boquete"},
        {value: "Academia Internacional David", label: "Academia Internacional David"}]
```

The 2 textfields I'm using:

```
              <TextField 
               select
               margin="normal"
               value={colegio}
               helperText="Seleccione la sede"
               onChange={handleChangeColegio}
               >
                   {sedes.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
          </TextField>

          <TextField 
               select
               margin="normal"
               value={grado}
               helperText="Seleccione el grado"
               onChange={handleChangeGrado}
               >
                   {grados.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
          </TextField>
```

Comment: Can you add your code here, preferably on codesandbox?

Comment: I'll add it here + sandbox 1 sec

Comment: I think I did it ? [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-forked-4ou91?file=/index.js) is first time I actually try to use sandbox lol

Comment: Your codesandbox doesn't run

Comment: [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wave-1zd8t?file=/src/App.js) that one should work just double check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the list of options of the second `Select` in a state. Then when you select an option in the first one, update the state based on the selected value:

```
const [options2, setOptions2] = useState(allOptions2);

const handleChangeOption1 = (event) => {
  const selectedValue = event.target.value;

  if (selectedValue === options1[0].value) {
    setOptions2(allOptions2.slice(0, 9)); // get the first 9 items
  } else {
    setOptions2(allOptions2.slice(-6)); // get the last 6 items
  }
  setOption1(selectedValue);
};
```

```
<TextField
  select
  onChange={handleChangeOption1}
>
  {options1.map((option) => (...))}
</TextField>

<TextField select>
  {options2.map((option) => (...))}
</TextField>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: yeah this does what I need thank you very much